# Registering multiple AuthenticationProviders regarding WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to register multiple `AuthenticationProvider`s in a Spring Boot security config class, like in the following snippet borrowed from [this repository](https://github.com/havinhphu188/spring-security-in-action-source/blob/98a34b30c44c48ddc3ce66bb0f3f932543ff29a7/ssia-ch11-ex1-s2/src/main/java/com/laurentiuspilca/ssia/config/SecurityConfig.java#L32):

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(otpAuthenticationProvider)
        .authenticationProvider(usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

However, I could not find the correct solution from the Spring Boot [deprecation note](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter). Do you know how to register multiple `AuthenticationProvider`s without using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Comment: the code presented in Spring Security In Action is deprecated, and he is building hiw own authorization server. That is not how you do it, today spring has their own authorization server projekt and this is what should be used instead. The book is 3 years old, lots of things happen in 3 years.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Could you please introduce an up-to-date source for studying and solving such problems?

Comment: can i ask why havnt you tried reading the official documentation before asking?

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I mentioned in my question, I have read the deprecation note and related documents. However, I was unable to figure out how to implement my custom scenario. That's why I decided to ask a question.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have just seen the article you wrote about spring boot + JWT, and I wish I had seen it before asking my question. However, the main advantage of asking the question was that I got to know you and I am very happy about this acquaintance.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(otpAuthenticationProvider)
        .authenticationProvider(usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

}
```